# Programmatically assign macro in Excel to a picture added from file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an inventory worksheet inside inventory.xlsm workbook with lots of product pictures. I use a macro called `AddPicFromFile()` to add a picture from desktop and fit it into the cell. I require that when the macro is run it would do its usual stuff, but also assign a macro called ClickResizeImage() to the picture shape.

```
Sub AddPicFromFile()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imagePath As String
Dim imgLeft As Double
Dim imgTop As Double

Set ws = ActiveSheet
imagePath = "C:\Users\Secret\Desktop\untitled-1.jpg"
imgLeft = ActiveCell.Left
imgTop = ActiveCell.Top

'Width & Height = -1 means keep original size
ws.Shapes.AddPicture _
    Filename:=imagePath, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=imgLeft + 0.75, _
    Top:=imgTop + 0.75, _
    Width:=42, _
    Height:=42

End Sub
```

And this here is the ClickResizeImage() which of course works fine as a standalone.

```
Sub ClickResizeImage()
Dim shp As Shape
    Dim big As Single, small As Single

    Dim shpDouH As Double, shpDouOriH As Double
    big = 8
    small = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With shp
        shpDouH = .Height
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        shpDouOriH = .Height

        If Round(shpDouH / shpDouOriH, 2) = big Then
            .ScaleHeight small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
        Else
            .ScaleHeight big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoBringToFront
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I tried adding `Selection.OnAction = "ClickResizeImage"` to the code but it comes up with Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. One part of the problem is AddPicFromFile doesn't select the shape and that's required by ClickResizeImage to work, as it does work as standalone module. I just want to combine them into one macro basically.

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: I want that when I add the picture into the sheet the macro will also assign the macro `ClickResizeImage` for the picture shape. It's too slow to right click and assign macro for each picture manually.

Answer (score 3):

This will assign a macro to a `Shape`:

```
Sub stepup()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    s.OnAction = "ClickResizeImage"
End Sub
```

Comment: I made a new module for your code and tried it first as standalone by selecting the picture and then running it, but it doesn't assign the macro for it. If it worked I could add `Call stepup` at the end of AddPicFromFile and that should do the trick.

Comment: I got it working as standalone macro now by eliminating the 'Dim s As Shape' and 'Set s = Activesheet.Shapes(1)'. So it's just a single line of code. I then proceeded to try and add 'Call stepup' at the end of AddPicFromFile macro but it gives a: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

How would I link it to run both macros with just 1 button exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to the end of your `AddPicFromFile` code:

```
ws.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).OnAction = "ClickResizeImage"
```

Comment: It now gives Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Just to double check: Have you changed your code at all from above? Is `ws` still set to your `ActiveSheet`? Did you paste my line of code just above `End Sub`, at the bottom of your `AddPicFromFile` sub, on its own line? If all is OK then I'm not sure what to suggest, your code with the extra line works great for me. Nice macro.

Comment: ```Sub AddPicFromFile() Dim ws As Worksheet Dim imagePath As String Dim imgLeft As Double Dim imgTop As Double Set ws = ActiveSheet imagePath = "C:\Users\Secret\Desktop\untitled-1.jpg" imgLeft = ActiveCell.Left imgTop = ActiveCell.Top 'Width & Height = -1 means keep original size ws.Shapes.AddPicture _ Filename:=imagePath, _ LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _ SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _ Left:=imgLeft + 0.75, _ Top:=imgTop + 0.75, _ Width:=42, _ Height:=42 ws.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).OnAction = "ClickResizeImage" End Sub```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in reply. Yeah I added your code on it's own line just before `End Sub` and `ws` is still there too. How odd it works for you, but for me it requests for debugging and that line is the one marked yellow. It adds the picture but fails before assigning the macro. Can someone else verify whether it works or doesn't for them?

Comment: I've also tried to remove all the other macros from the entire workbook, including modules. So it cannot be some of those preventing this from running. I'm using Excel 2016.